# How do I get Windows and Ubuntu on Mac via bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, macos, ubuntu, mac, boot-camp

Im running a mac, and currently have bootcamp running Mac OS X Snow Leopard, And Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit,

However I want to make a 3rd partition for Ubuntu 10.4 64 bit,

Does anyone know how to do this? or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you considered Wubi? It might save you some time. http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer

Comment: What is Wubi? Via bootcamp atm I can load my mac to either Windows 7 or Mac OSx snow leopard, and I want to put Linux on there also.

Comment: I do not like the Wubi solution...
It's not the real deal if someone really wants to use totally his hardware with ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer may slightly miss your question, but may be a solution to what you are trying to do.

The most painless way to create a multiboot system on the mac is to use [refit](http://refit.sourceforge.net/).
If the icons hurt your eyes because they do not look mactastic enough, just use these [icons](http://enjoy974.deviantart.com/art/rEFIt-Icons-Pack-124675767).

Make sure to install Ubuntu's bootloader onto the Ubuntu partition and make sure you update refit's mbr table after the install is done.

Comment: Yer, i currently use refit for windows and mac partitions. Its great. However, the problem lies inherently with bootcamp.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Well, basically, im using bootcamp to run windows and mac, i want to know how to get linux on there aswell

Comment: Bootcamp supports one OS besides MacOS but if you just install Ubuntu (partition resizing during installation) and install the bootloader onto the Ubuntu partitio refit will find it alongside MacOS and Windows. Thats how i did it. Just dont forget to update refits mbr-table.

Comment: You got any useful links that might help me through it?

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally tested this method, however there is a [Triple Boot tutorial](http://wiki.onmac.net/index.php/Triple_Boot_via_BootCamp) for Apple hardware to triple boot with Windows and Linux. I hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

I have an iMac with Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Windows 7 partitions. For Ubuntu, since I used it less frequently than OS X or Windows, I avoided the complexity and hassle of trying to set up a triple-boot Boot Camp by running Ubuntu as a virtual machine under [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/).

If you don't want to shell out for VMWare Fusion, you can do the same with the free Sun [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) virtualization software.

A [Google search for "Ubuntu virtual images"](http://www.google.com/search?q=Ubuntu%20virtual%20images) turns up a number of places where you can download pre-built Ubuntu virtual machines, making it even easier to get up and running.

I realize that doesn't directly answer your question -- which specified "via Boot Camp" -- but it may provide equivalent functionality with a much lower technical threshold and less effort.